# Вывести в IP-адрес в поле редактирования

Tags: c++builder, winsock, c++

Всем привет.
Нужно на С++ Builder выводить IP в `Edit`, все работает хорошо. Но проблема в том, что `h` никогда не равен нулю, если комп не в сети, то выводит 127.0.0.1, а мне бы хотелось, чтобы выводилось

```
ShowMessage("Вы не в сети.");
```

Вот код:

```
const int WSVer = 0x101;
WSAData wsaData;
hostent *h;
char Buf[128];
if (WSAStartup(WSVer, &wsaData) == 0)
{
  if (gethostname(&Buf[0], 128) == 0)
  {
    h = gethostbyname(&Buf[0]);
    if (h != NULL)
      Edit4->Text=(inet_ntoa (*(reinterpret_cast<in_addr *>(*(h->h_addr_list)))));
    else
      ShowMessage("Вы не в сети.");
    WSACleanup();
  }                                        
}
```

Может, дадите ссылки хорошие на эту тему.
Всем заранее большое спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, просто проверять, что IP не подходит под маску 127.*?

Comment: как?я думала, может сверять с h, то есть ввести еще одну переменную(например f),но я не пойму, какой тип имеет h.Выдает ошибку, пробовала и strstr сверять, ничего не работает,не компилируется(

Comment: посмотрите исходник типа данных hostent, либо гугл спасет: http://netcode.ru/cpp/?lang=&katID=19&skatID=171&artID=5055. перебираем h_addr_list (свойство структуры hostent, экземпляром которой является h) и если хоть один элемент равен 127.*, то сеть не подключена.

Comment: спасибо, уже придумала(правда в эдит выводит, но мне главное было вывести сообщение):
<pre>Edit4->Text=(inet_ntoa (*(reinterpret_cast<in_addr *>(*(h->h_addr_list)))));
    if(Edit4->Text == "127.0.0.1")
    ShowMessage("Вы не в сети.");</pre>

Answer (score 1):

А он и не будет равен 0.
Отлавливайте диапазон LocalHost и выводите то что Вам нужно.

Comment: можете объяснить поподробнее, или пример какой, или ссылку почитать, что-то я на эту тему не могу найти ничего хорошего.